# How i make array from Map

Tags: java, arrays, dictionary, hashmap

I have a `String[] arr` and i want get a array from `Map`.
How i can do it? like a list?

```
Map<String, Long> map = new HashMap<String. Long>();
String[] arr;
int size;
size = map.size();
arr = String.valueOf(size);
```

I need to get total number of elements in Map

Comment: Array of what, keys? (assuming that is the String type in your code)

Comment: To get collections of the keys and values, use the `keySet()` and `values()` methods. Consult the `Collection`’s JavaDoc to figure out how to transfer it to an array.

Comment: I want get `map.size();`

Comment: Did you try... `map.size()`?

Comment: I think you have answered your question.

Comment: Yes i tried but, shows to change Sting[] to String

Comment: `map.size()` to initialize the array, `map.keySet().iterator` to fill it.

Comment: i already tried `int size = map.size` and `arr = String.valuesOf(size)`

Comment: @gmendes You need to give an example of the kind of output you need or rephrase the question.

Comment: By total size of the map, do you mean the length of all string keys in the map combined?

Comment: Yes, it's total map size

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends if you want an array out of your **keys** (`Set`), or out of your **values** (`List`).

You may want to read the `toArray` javadoc from `List` and `Set` as well.

```
final Map<String, Long> map = new HashMap<>();

final String[] keyArr = map.keySet().toArray(new String[map.keySet().size()]);
final Long[] valArr = map.values().toArray(new Long[map.values().size()]);
```

---

**Edit:**

Alright... so... given your latest edit, is this what you're looking for?

```
String[] arr = new String[map.size()];
```

Kinda hard to guess what you need.

Comment: I don't understand your solution. I need use Long in my case

Comment: It sounds like you may need to slow down a bit and think more precisely about what you need. You need to get an array of _what_ from a map? And why did you say in the comments that you want to get `map.size()`? What is it _exactly_ you need? It's really hard to answer the question otherwise.

Comment: i edit my question, should clarify

Comment: @gmendes Still doesn't make any sense. `valueOf` does not return a `String[]`, dude.

Comment: It sounds like you want an array of Strings which contains each of the keys in the map? (Note that this is a more specific phrasing than "an array from Map.") If so, the second line of code in this answer, the one that starts `final String[]` is exactly what you need.

Comment: In first time you use Integer, but the second helped

Comment: @gmendes See edited answer. BUT, I'm pretty sure the piece of code with `Long` is what you need.

Comment: i will try your answer. I guess it's works

Answer (score 0):

Read the javadoc.

map.keySet().toArray();

Answer (score 0):

`String[] arr = new String[map.size()];` works
`String[] Arr = map.keySet().toArray(new String[map.keySet().size()]);` as well.